# USB CD Drive not mounted as cdrom

Tags: usb, mount

I have an external USB CD drive:

```
# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 13fd:1140 Initio Corporation <-- 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 
Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But it is not mounted as /dev/cdrom or something only as /dev/sg0 and /dev/sda

```
usb 1-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=13fd, idProduct=0840
usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
usb 1-1.5: Product: External
usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: Generic
usb 1-1.5: SerialNumber: 303030303030303030303030
usb-storage 1-1.5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.5:1.0
scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  External         1.14 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

which are inaccessible:

```
# wodim -dev=/dev/sg0 --devices
wodim: Overview of accessible drives (0 found) :
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
# wodim -dev=/dev/sda --devices
wodim: Overview of accessible drives (0 found) :
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------------------------------------------------------------------


# sudo lshw -c disk
*-disk                  
   description: SCSI Disk
   physical id: 0.0.0
   bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/sda
   configuration: logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
```

What can I do to make it recognized as cddrive?

Comment: with the device attached what does `sudo lshw -c disk` show?

Comment: Insert a CD/DVD and you'll either see it on your desktop, or in the `Files` (Nautilus) file manager. sda is your hard disk.

Comment: @heynnema I tried already to insert a data cd and an audio cd same result.
I use an RPi with no harddrive just /dev/mmcblk...

Comment: What OS/version are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu server for RPi  with kernel 4.9.36